# NSURLRequest with more than one url!

Tags: iphone, pdf, sdk, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

Hey, I'm using NSURLRequest and the NSURLConnection to download pdf.`

> NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MyPDF.pdf"]  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];
>   NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

How could I make so I can have more than one URL Link to PDFs in the NSURLRequest line? Instead of just having one URL "MyPDF.pdf".

Thanks in advance!

---

Jacob L

Comment: What would you expect that to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. If you want to request multiple PDFs (or whatever), you need to make multiple requests.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Thank I am going to try this with compressed files and decompress them.